# How to Simulate array.remove(int) in a Language that only Allows array.add(int)

Tags: arrays, optimization, abstraction

I am trying to implement an algorithm in an exotic programming language that requires that I remove an element from a one-dimensional array, but the language does not have a method for removing element x at index i.

These methods are available for array.[method]() :

- add(x)      --- push x and resize length + 1
- resize(x)   --- new length = x
- count() --- returns the length of the array

Is there a way I can write my own array method or remove method, using primitive data types, basic control flow, and variables?

I have considered to use an array with both retained and discarded items together with an array of booleans to represent *include* == true/false. The arrays would share the same index, but I am not sure this would be the most computationally effective way to approach this.

Comment: How frequently do you expect to remove an item? You could copy everything to a temporary array, resize the original to `0` and copy whatever you want back. It's not exactly efficient but it's straight forward.

Comment: You don't specify if you have the ability to GET an item from the array

Comment: And this is not an exotic programming language: this is a homework-assignment programming language.

Comment: @hayesti The need for removal is random and it is difficult to estimate the probability. The procedure will be repeated for 2*2*240 arrays * rand[1,10] elements.

Comment: @iAdjunct I'm a PhD student in Neuroscience implementing an experiment design in a programming language called Presentation (NeuroBehavioralSystems): https://www.neurobs.com/pres_docs/html/04_reference/03_pcl_reference/01_basic_types/01_array.htm

Comment: @noumenal `array` is unsorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Staighforward solution which use no additional array. Run time and amount of memory used is depend on `count` and `resize` subroutines and access by index `[]` implementation details which aren't described in documentation:

```
sub
   remove( array< int,1 >& initial_array, int item_to_remove )
begin
   loop
      int i = 1
      int removed_count = 0
      int count = initial_array.count()
   until
      i > count - removed_count;
   begin
      if( initial_array[i] != item_to_remove ) then
         # remove item by replacing it with the item from the tail
         initial_array[i] = initial_array[count - removed_count];
         removed_count = removed_count + 1
         continue;
      end;
      i = i + 1;
   end;
   # cut the tail
   initial_array.resize(count - removed_count);
end;

array<int> foo[] = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 3 };
remove( foo, 3 );  # after execution foo must contain { 1, 2, 2 }
```

More complication solution will be to implement more appropriate for your purposes data structure. As my undersanding goes you can achive this by implementing [PCL Extension](https://www.neurobs.com/pres_docs/html/03_presentation/12_extensions/04_pcl_extensions/01_creating_pcl_extensions/index.html)

As @iAdjunct pointed out it is interesting why `array` doesn't have this method in first place.

Comment: I like your idea, but it requires an additional int array. I am currently looking into different options for extensions, but I would like to minimize dependencies for this project - especially for such a simple task.

Comment: @noumenal I rewrote subroutine to use no additional array

Comment: Wow! Thanks. This is much more efficient. I will try this. I will apply this to the algorithm sort-and-sweep for 2D collision detection.

Comment: @noumenal, I update my answer. Amount of memory used is really depends of implementation of `resize` method. I found no information about it in documentation. So some performance measurement need to be done in order undersand which solution is better

Comment: I will use clock.time() for profiling. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to preserve order:

```
indexToRemove = 3 ;
lastIndex = array.count()-1 ;
array.fill ( indexToRemove , indexToRemove-1 , array[lastIndex] , 0 ) ;
array.resize ( lastIndex ) ;
```

If you do, you have a few options:

- Do the above several times to shift everything over.
- Create a new array with everything between the index you want to remove and the end, then resize the array, then add all the other elements back in.
- Create a new array with everything you want, then assign the old array.

But a more underlying question is why this language doesn't have a remove function. Is the intention that anything you'd do in this language is in a domain that doesn't have a concept of removal?

Comment: Most often, I have found that the language specification is vague. I just might file a request to the language developers for a remove future.